# Link structure issue of wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

How to change the link structure of any blog post that is shared on any social media platform. This is a News website designed on WordPress Platform. The problem specifically arises when any blogpost written in telugu is shared on Whatsapp. The link structure after sharing is showing up something similar to "%0%0%0%0%8%8

[image]

I want the shared link to have the title of the blog post and the featured image of the post